# Query the JVM heap for specfic Objects

Tags: java

Is there a GUI tool that is able to "attach" it self to a JVM (Remote/Local) which allows one to "query" for specific object types on the heap and return the results and also allow one to inspect its properties. Even better, allows one to modify the property directly?

For instance. I have a JVM with Employee Beans cached in memory. And the "tool" allows me to say get all Employee Bean instances. And it returns a set of results. And i can inspect individual Employee Bean and maybe alter the "address field" directly without any code.

Comment: Never heard of anything like that. Though, it should be possible to implement it using the java debug interface. But the application must be started in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried: **jvisualvm** that comes together with java jdk (I have it here:/usr/lib/jvm/jdkx.y.z/bin/)? Is it not enough? Sampler and Profiler tabs plus snapshot capability with filtering options should give you what you need.